# Is it possible to merge unions?

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I have this struct that defines a 32-bit unsigned integer.

```
struct WORD
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            BYTE byte1; // lowest
            BYTE byte2;
            BYTE byte3;
            BYTE byte4; // highest
        };
        uint32_t raw;
    };
};
```

I want to create subclasses of this struct for example

```
struct CPSR : WORD
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t mode: 5;
            uint32_t thumbState : 1;
            uint32_t fiqDisable : 1;
            uint32_t irqDisable : 1;
            uint32_t unused : 20;
            uint32_t V : 1;
            uint32_t C : 1;
            uint32_t Z : 1;
            uint32_t N : 1;
        };
        uint32_t raw;
    };
};
```

I want this struct to be able to access and modify fields `byteX` from the parent struct. The changes made to `byteX` must also be reflected in the child struct's internal struct. In order to do that, the union from the parent struct must be merged into this child struct. In other words, I want this child struct to behave the exact same way as

```
struct CPSR
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t mode: 5;
            uint32_t thumbState : 1;
            uint32_t fiqDisable : 1;
            uint32_t irqDisable : 1;
            uint32_t unused : 20;
            uint32_t V : 1;
            uint32_t C : 1;
            uint32_t Z : 1;
            uint32_t N : 1;
        };

        struct
        {
            BYTE byte1; // lowest
            BYTE byte2;
            BYTE byte3;
            BYTE byte4; // highest
        };

        uint32_t raw;
    };
};
```

Is it possible to merge unions like this?

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/7beresKaz

Comment: Wouldn't you need to give the `struct`s names in order to access them? (Not the `struct` types, the impilcit data structures themselves.)

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA What's wrong with anonymous structs?

Comment: The layout of bit fields is implementation-dependent. You cannot rely on anything here. Regarding _"The changes made to byteX must also be reflected in the child struct's internal struct"_: that's a violation of the rules of unions. If you need to reliably read/write these fields in a 32-bit value, use shifts and masks. You can wrap this behavior in your own class. Essentially that does exactly what bit-fields do under the hood, except it's portable and does not abuse `union`.

Comment: Nothing, but an anonymous `struct` doesn't mean one which has no name, just that it has no *type* name. You still need a variable name for the `struct` itself in order to access it. something like `struct {BYTE value[4];} bytes;` would be fine, and would accessed by `my_word.bytes.value[0];` or the like.

Comment: @JimmyYang Anonymous structs are actually not allowed in C++. They are a C-only feature. Some compilers allow them in C++ as a compiler extension if you don't ask them to use strict standard compliance. In C++ only unions can be anonymous like that.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA Anonymous structures without name in another struct or union are allowed in C (since C11), but not C++. The names of the members are directly accessible in the enclosing scope as members. C++ has the same concept for anonymous unions though. Some compilers allow anonymous structures in C++ as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance won't work.  I think you're looking for:

```
struct CPSR
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t mode: 5;
            uint32_t thumbState : 1;
            uint32_t fiqDisable : 1;
            uint32_t irqDisable : 1;
            uint32_t unused : 20;
            uint32_t V : 1;
            uint32_t C : 1;
            uint32_t Z : 1;
            uint32_t N : 1;
        };

        WORD w;
    };
};
```

Plus what @Schol-R-LEA said.

I know that's not quite the same thing, but I think it's the closest you're going to get.  And you're not type-punning, I hope...